# Maven: Error occurred during initialization of VM java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object

Tags: java, linux, maven, ubuntu, java-8

I have a VM with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

I've installed Maven with "`sudo apt-get install maven`" but when I type the command "`mvn`" I get the following error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
```

The currently Java version installed is `openjdk version "1.8.0_312"`

[SOLVED] The Java version installed was wrong. I've installed the 586 version instead of 64bit version.

Comment: did you set JAVA_HOME?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to configure JAVA_HOME and set the value to your java installation (which java).
Also, maven may require a jdk installation not jre.
You should provide some more details of like the output of **mvn --version**. This output will tell you which java maven is using.

Comment: My JAVA_HOME is: "/opt/jdk1.8.0_202-i586"

which java points to "/usr/bin/java" while mvn --version have the same error: "error occurred ..."

Thanks

Comment: I suspect your maven installation might have issues. Try uninstalling  first and then do a clean install. Here is a guide on how to do that https://www.how2shout.com/linux/how-to-install-maven-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts-jammy/

Comment: To add more https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/1006790_1.html Your jdk1.8.0_202-i586 might not be the right one for your OS!!

Comment: I've noticed that in my "/opt/jdk1.8.0_202-i586/jre/lib" I don't have a rt.jar but rt.pack.
What does it mean? Tnx